# 'missing \item' error when using `\addtocontents` to insert a new line in the table of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, errors, tocloft

According to the requirements of my school, the List of Tables and List of Figures must have an underlined **Table** and **Page** headings right above the columns of table of contents

> A “Page” column heading that appears below the major heading, is aligned flush with the right margin, is underlined, and appears between the major heading and the first entry. Page numbers must appear under this column heading.

My code works and yields the desired output

[image]

However, I get the error 'Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \addvspace {10\p@ }'.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage[TS1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Georgia}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}

\usepackage{gensymb}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\pagestyle{plain}

\clearpage
\listoffigures

\clearpage
\listoftables

\clearpage
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect \uline{Table} \hspace{\fill} \uline{Page}}
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect \uline{Figure} \hspace{\fill} \uline{Page}}


\chapter{Introduction}

\begin{figure}

    \caption{A Caption of a Figure}

\end{figure}

\begin{table}

    \caption{A Caption of a Table}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `\addtocontents` after the start of the first `\chapter` and load hyperref as last package

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage[TS1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Georgia}




\usepackage{gensymb}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\pagestyle{plain}

\clearpage
\listoffigures

\clearpage
\listoftables

\clearpage
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter






\chapter{Introduction}


\addtocontents{lot}{\protect \uline{Table} \hspace{\fill} \uline{Page}}
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect \uline{Figure} \hspace{\fill} \uline{Page}}
\begin{figure}

    \caption{A Caption of a Figure}

\end{figure}

\begin{table}

    \caption{A Caption of a Table}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]